# Sum of this eries: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp(1-p)^{k-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp(1-p)^{k-1}$

Can someone help me evaluate this sum?  I couldn't even start, I have just written down the first couple of elements, but didn't help either.

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Can you compute the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^k?$$ Now what happens if you differentiate term-by-term?

Comment: I can, that is a geometric series. And the term-by-term derivatives of this are the terms of my original problem. If I just differentiate the sum of this do I get the sum of my problem?

Comment: You get something very close. $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}$. What do you have to do to get the original and how is that related to what the geometric series in my answer converges to?

Comment: Lookup the theorem about differentiating term-by-term. Hint: Yes, you can differentiate the expression $1/p$ and get $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}=-1/p^2$... Based on what I just wrote what must the answer then be?

Answer (score 1):

let the sum begin at k=0 and write instead of $kp(1-p)^k$ the expression $(k+1)p(1-P)^k$.
Then expand the expression behind the sigma sign.

greetings,

calculus.